# How to skip rows above tables in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading tables from several html files using Pandas read_html and putting them under one another in an Excel file using Pandas' ExcelWriter.

The problem I'm having is that each file has 14 lines of junk data above the table that I'd like to get rid of; I've found threads that recommend using skip rows which does get rid of the data above the table but also drops the first 14 rows from my table.

- Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can get rid of the lines above my tables without losing any rows in the table?
- Also, I've used index_col = 0 to get rid of the indices on the rows but I can't find the syntax to get rid of the  indices along the columns?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

This is my read_html call:

```
for i in os.listdir(dl):
    if "Export" in i:
        for df in pd.read_html(i, skiprows = 14, index_col = 0):
            df_list.append(df)
dfs = pd.concat(df_list)
```

This is the format of my files with several lines of junk data and the table immediately beneath:

===========================================================

GPF Purchase Order Forecasts

Generation Date:  2018-08-30
Order Date:  2018-09-08
Delivery Date  0000-00-00

Vendor No.:                             ALL

Warehouse:                          ALL

===========================================================

Warehouse   Item No.    Item Description    UPC Number  Pack Size   Forecast

XXXX    XXXX    XXXX    XXXX    XXXX    XXXX    XXXX    XXXX    XXXX

The first 100 lines of the html file:

```
<!-- For export to excel style needs to be written on the page-->

<style type="text/css">

    .Header

    {

        font-weight: bold;

    }

    .HeadUnderline

    {

        font-weight: bold;

        text-decoration: underline;

    }

</style>

</head>

<body id="portal">

<form name="frmMain" method="post" action="Export.aspx?DcNbr=0&amp;VendorNbr=0&amp;OrdDate=2018-09-01&amp;GenDate=2018-08-30&amp;DivNbr=0&amp;DelDate=0000-00-00" id="frmMain">

<div>

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTg0NDMyMzg5OGQYAQUJZ3ZSZXN1bHRzDzwrAAwBCAIBZC77FhJcYYUB/Yk3jdfFNSAWWS9MSP5BghZFEKqOFLXh" />
```

```
<!-- c1under - to use this page as a popup window without the header change the id from rlHeader 

    to rlStyle. The rlFooter literal could be removed if you do not want the footer on the popup window.

     -->

<div id="main-content-area" style="vertical-align: top;">

    <table width="100%" border="0" bordercolor="#FFCC00" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="vertical-align: top">

        <tr style="vertical-align: top" align="center">

            <td style="vertical-align: top; border: solid 2 black;" align="center" colspan="8">

                <span id="lblAppTitle" class="HeadUnderline">GPF Purchase Order Forecasts</span>

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td colspan="8">

                &nbsp;

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 27px">

            <td align='right' colspan="8">

                <span id="lblGenDate" class="Header">Generation Date:</span>&nbsp;

                <span id="lblGenDateValue">2018-08-30</span>

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td colspan="8">

                <span id="lblOrderDate" class="Header">Order Date:</span>&nbsp;

                <span id="lblOrderDateValue">2018-09-01</span>

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td colspan="8">

                <span id="lblDeliveryDate" class="Header">Delivery Date</span>&nbsp;

                <span id="lblDeliveryDateValue">0000-00-00</span>

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td colspan="8">

                &nbsp;

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 27px">

            <td align="right" colspan="7">

                <span id="lblVendorNumber" class="Header">Vendor No.:</span>&nbsp;

            </td>

            <td align="left">

                <span id="lblVendorNumberValue">ALL</span>

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td id="vendorAddress" align="right"></td>



            <td colspan="7">

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td colspan="8">

                &nbsp;

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 27px">

            <td align='right' colspan="7">

                <span id="lblWarehouse" class="Header">Warehouse:</span>&nbsp;

            </td>

            <td align="left">

                <span id="lblWarehouseValue">ALL</span>

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td id="depotAddress" align="left" colspan="8"></td>



        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td colspan="8">

                &nbsp;

            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your `html` file? Maybe you have all that junk data in one line, and if you `skiprows=14` you end up skipping other 13 lines which are already data in your table

Comment: I've added the first part of the html file until the start of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in os.listdir(dl):
    if "Export" in i:
       # Read out all html tables into list of dataframes
       data = pd.read_html(i, index_col=0)

       # Drop first table containing junk data
       data = data[1:]

       # Merge with already existing list of dataframes
       df_list += data

dfs = pd.concat(df_list)
```